# помогите с решением задачи js

Tags: javascript, циклы

Суть задачи :

```
 function getPeople(handshake) {
 let people = 0;
while (handshake >=people ) {
handshake++;
}
 return people ;
}




console.log( getPeople(1) ); // 1 
console.log( getPeople(3) ); // 2
console.log( getPeople(6) ); // 3 
console.log( getPeople(10) ); // 4 
console.log( getPeople(15) ); // 5
console.log( getPeople(120) ); //  ?
```

Нужно вычислить сколько было людей в кабинете если было 120 рукопожатий

Comment: 1 рукопожатие если один человек? Три рукопожатия у двух человек? Там что, каждый сам себе ещё руки жмёт?

Comment: А что за бред написан внутри функции? Он даже не вернёт те неправильные ответы которые указаны в комментариях

Comment: А для получения ответа нужно не цикл, а решить квадратное уравнение

Comment: Зачем нужно было идти на SO если первый вопрос на гугле дает искомый ответ? Для чего это здесь? Не думаю, что человек не умея пользоваться гуглом, смог задать вопрос на SO.  Все же я предполагаю, что на нас тестят новый самообучающийся ИИ - который пытается задать хороший вопрос..

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato тоже есть ощущение, что некоторые вопросы, как и ответы - пишут не люди. Вполне реально, почему нет..

Answer (score 1):

Если у тебя X человек то рукопожатий будет (N(N+1))/2 где N=X-1
Чтобы найти сколько будет человек просто сделай обратную формулу

Обновлено:
**x = (sqrt(8*y+1)+1)/2** (x - человек, y - рукопожатия)

```
console.log((Math.sqrt(8*handshake+1)+1)/2);
```

Например для 6 человек 15 рукопожатий если я не ошибся, все линии между точками 6 угольника это рукопожатия
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для let handshake = 120
console.log((Math.sqrt(8*handshake+1)+1)/2); ==16